# Field mapping for import definition changed by itself

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, import

I am trying to create a Contact Import activity by following [this pervious topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236654/automate-importing-of-sms-mobileconnect-data) to update SMS optout status (with intention to run this on scheduled automation) but I am getting "NotFound" error. The issue seems to be the field mapping.

I have confirmed the 18-digit ContactKey in the imported file was correct.

The import definition was created in Contact Builder > Imports > Create. The target destination is "List"/ "All Contacts - Mobile".

I following [the offical article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_prepare_file_for_import.htm&type=5) to prepare the import file and it has the following fields

- _ContactKey
- _Status
- _MobileNumber
- _Locale

This is the mapping I had when I setup the import definition

[image: Import definition mapping during setup]

When I check the import definition again, the mapping is all over the place

[image: Import definition mapping after setup]

The system has parent/ child BUs. The import activity is in the child BU. I have tried to

- run the automation with the configured "Import Mobile Contact" from child BU
- run a SSJS at the parent BU to trigger the above automation at the child BU

I have setup automation to update All Subscribers before without issue.

I am not sure what(if) I have done wrong or this is a platform issue that needs to go to SF Support?

Any help on how to overcome this import mapping issue OR a better way to automated SMS optout would be highly appreciated.